# jQuery sortable POST correct order to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a form. This form has items in it. I'm doing something very similar to [this](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/). Every item is sortable (draggable) - I'm using jQuery sortable. 
When I submit the form to the MVC controller - the order is lost, and I end up with the default order in the db. How can I fix this?

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", autocomplete = "off" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div id="itemEditor">

                @if (Model.Items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                    {
                        Html.RenderPartial("ItemEntryEditor", item);
                    }
                }
            </div>

            <div id="addAnother" class="btn-add-item btn-mnu">Add Item</div>

            <div style="float:right">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-mnu btn-default" />
            </div>
        }
```

Partial View

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items")){
<div class="container-item holder1">
    <span class="icono-trash remove-item"></span>
    <div class="row-main-inline">
        <span>*</span>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category_Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

        <div class="row-contents">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category_Name)
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="row-main-inline">
        <span>*</span>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="row-contents">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "custom-input form-control inp-b", autocomplete = "off" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-main-inline">
        <span>*</span>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

        <div class="row-contents">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "custom-input form-control inp-b" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-item">
        <div class="row-main-inline">
            <span>*</span>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })

            <div class="row-contents">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "textarea-custom custom-input form-control inp-b" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-main-inline">
            <span>*</span>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Just_Statement, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="row-contents">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Just_Statement, new { @class = "custom-input form-control textarea-custom inp-b" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Just_Statement, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

jQuery

```
                $(function () {
                    $("#itemEditor").sortable();

                    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
                        $.get('/Requisition/ItemEntryRow', function (template) {
                            $("#itemEditor").append(template);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you post a sort key and is that key updated when you drag/reorder items?

Comment: Every item has a unique id, but when I try $('itemEditor').sortable('toArray'), I get the error - cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toArray'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in my partial view. HTML was rendering incorrectly and it messed up the order of items.

instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items"))
{
<div class="container-item holder1">
....
</div>
}
```

should be

```
<div class="container-item holder1">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items"))
{
....
}
</div>
```